# Anti-causal/Non-causal relationship

Tags: word-choice, usage, vocabulary, set-phrases, colloquial-language

How do I form a sentence of these patterns "X does not arise from Y", "X not due to Y", "X not because of Y", "There are other reasons for X". Since obviously I cannot simply slap ない onto から or ので to form an "anti-causal" particle.

Would the below constructions work?:

- Xの原因はYじゃない
- Xの原因はYだけではない
- Xの原因は他がある
- XはYだからじゃない
- XでもYはない
- XとYは関係がない

Are there better options for this type of relationship between X and Y? Or do more colloquial forms or set phrases exist for stating anti/non-cause? I'm not sure if my constructions sound unnatural. The way I constructed those statements feel quite literal to me.

Comment: The English constructions you cite aren't very natural to me. Could you give a few realistic examples please?

Comment: @Axioplase: They seem pretty natural to me. "The explosion is not due to pressure.", "The explosion is not because of the pressure", "The explosion did not arise from the pressure", "There are other reasons for the explosion". They all sound perfectly fine to me.

Comment: ah, ok.  I asked for examples, because the lack of implication means one could relate almost anything.  And from nonsensical sentences, it's hard to make some rational explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, I assume that *X* and *Y* take the form of a sentence like `僕が遅刻した`.

- If you want to presuppose that *X* and *Y* both happened, and assert that the former is not due to the latter, then a simple expression is:

> *X* のは *Y* せいではない
>   *Y* せいで　*X* のではない

Some of your examples can also be used:

> *X* 原因は *Y* からではない
>   *X* のは *Y* からではない

- If you want to presuppose that *X* and *Y* both happened, and assert that the former is not **only** due to the latter, then you can use your expressions:

> *X* 原因は *Y* からだけではない
>   *X* 原因は(*Y* ことの)他にある  [Corrected]

- If you want to be neutral whether *X* or *Y* happened, and assert that they are not related, then

> *X* かどうかは *Y* かどうかに依らない
>   *X* かどうかは *Y* かどうかに依存しない  [Academic]
>   *X* ことと *Y* ことは無関係だ

you can also use your expression:

> *X* ことと *Y* ことは関係(が)ない

Answer (score 3):

I think that "Yと関係なく、Xは…" is a fairly common expression.

You could naturally said "Xの原因はYではなく、" but you would have to say what the real reason is.

Xの原因はYとは限らない is maybe not bad either, to express that the reason of X is not limited to Y.

Xの原因はYじゃない  good, but very direct. You'll be asked "What is the reason of X then?"
Xの原因はYだけではない  similarly, "then, what else?"
Xの原因は他がある  I would say "ほかに(いくつか)ある"
XはYだからじゃない  hum, not very correct as far as I can think about it
XでもYはない  idem
XとYは関係がない  you just say it's unrelated, yes.

Some grammar points you can have a look at are "に(も)関わらず" and "を問わず" which basically mean "disregarding X" or "unrelated to X".  But they do not reflect anti-causality.

That's my best shot for now.